# access hbase in IDE Eclipse , java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: hadoop, hbase

When I write the java code to access hbase in IDE Eclipse, the messages "java.net.UnknownHostException" are always been shown.But hbase shell works well.
  I install the hadoop and hbase on a single linux node in pseudo distribution mode. And my hostname is yzd. Here are the /etc/hosts and hbase-site.xml:

```
/etc/hosts:
127.0.0.1 localhost yzd

hbase-site.xml:
      <property>
              <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
              <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
      </property>
      <property>
              <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
              <value>true</value>
      </property>
      <property>
              <name>dfs.replication</name>
              <value>1</value>
      </property>

Error message:
INFO [main] (HBaseRPC.java:117) - Using org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine for org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HMasterInterface
INFO [main] (HConnectionManager.java:596) - getMaster attempt 0 of 10 failed; retrying after sleep of 1000

java.net.UnknownHostException: unknown host: �  13846@yzdlocalhost
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.<init>(HBaseClient.java:224)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.getConnection(HBaseClient.java:954)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:816)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:141)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine.getProxy(WritableRpcEngine.java:174)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:295)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:272)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:324)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:579)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:94)
at com.hbasebook.hush.schema.SchemaManager.process(SchemaManager.java:126)
at com.hbasebook.hush.HushMain.main(HushMain.java:57)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of your local hbase matches the one you are using as a dependency in your pom. This should solve your issue. I was facing the same issue, I was using hbase in standalone mode. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all yzd is not host name, its domain name (You should prefer FQDN). Now this line

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: unknown host: �  13846@yzdlocalhost
```

clearly says that  **13846@yzdlocalhost** host is not there. Now you can do followings:

1. Use IP address instead of hostname in both hbase-site.xml and core-site.xml and check
2. Then use FQDN in etc/hosts file and tab-separate the values, now you can replace the IP with FQDN